# How do you access the fast travel map on the Wii U in Assassin's Creed III?

Tags: assassins-creed-3, wii-u

I'm playing Assassin's Creed III on a Wii U and I'm using a Wii U gamepad. How do I access the map? What button should I press? I'm not talking about the gamepad map; I'm talking about the big map.

Comment: Have you actually looked at the instruction manual?

Comment: Funny; not too long ago, someone asked the exact same question, and the answer is still `the map is always visible on the Wii U Gamepad`

Comment: I'm pretty sure the gamepad map is the only map there is.

Answer (score 2):

I just figured out how to open the fast travel map on Wii U: just press the minus button.

Comment: You appear to have made two accounts. [Go here to merge them.](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts)